# How to build an autocomplete search to search for some words in memory?

Tags: python

I am using a StringProperty to assign a list of (Singles) words through manual entry, and I was wondering if you could build some sort of autocompletion for a StringProperty.

Suppose I have a list of words, in a dictionary or a list like this:

```
my_word_list = ['car','house','cat','window','computer','...']
```

suppose I want to add a word to another list, regardless of whether it is present in the list `my_word_list`

```
new_word_list = []
```

Let's say that `new_word_list` , is stored in the script as a global variable

Using a StringProperty to assign a new word to the list, I'd like to have some sort of auto-completion in real time, to see if that word is already there in `my_word_list`, something like `.startswith()`

So there will be a suggested autocompletion, or at the very least, something like a search operator:

```
def search(self,context):
    names = []
    for n in my_word_list:
        names.append(n)
    names = sorted(names)
    return [(n,n,"") for n in names)]

class Test_OT_Autocomplete(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ """
    bl_idname = "test.autocomplete"
    bl_label = "Search "
    bl_property = "search"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}
    search: EnumProperty(name="search",description="",items=search)
    def execute(self,context):
        scn = context.scene
        scene_props = scn.scene_props
        scene_props.my_string= self.search
        return{'FINISHED'}
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.invoke_search_popup(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SceneProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_string: StringProperty()
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.scene_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SceneProps)
```

The basic idea is to auto-complete a StringProperty, any trick is welcome